# Drag and drop table cells and update db using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

long story short i’m making a game using php. 
Unfortunately I have come to a stop. I’m trying to make a interactive inventory, using JavaScript/Ajax and MySql database. The visual part will be a classic RPG grid based inventory(6x10).

My goal is that the user can drag and drop and item from on square to another, and if the other square is occupied then switch places. I want to updated the database for each action, using ajax so the page don’t refresh.

[image: Mockup of inventory and how the items are moved around]

I have build the database so it holds 60 slots(0-59), and each slot hold an ID.
The thought is that the ajax call moves the content of slot. (see sql file here: [Download link to sql file](http://nygaard91.com/download/inventory.sql))

I have made a php script that create an html table(6x10) and assign an id equal to the database column name.(php code)

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "game", "password", "game");

    $sql = "select * FROM inventory where UserID = '1'";
    $query  = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);
    $fetch = $query->fetch_object();

    $lineCount = 0;
?>

<style>
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        min-height:20px;
        min-width:20px;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <?php
        for($i=0; $i <= 59; $i++){
            if($lineCount == 0){
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td id='slot_".$i."'>".$fetch->{"slot_".$i}."</td>";
               $lineCount++;
            }elseif($lineCount==9){
               echo "<td id='slot_".$i."'>".$fetch->{"slot_".$i}."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
               $lineCount=0;
            }else{
               echo "<td id='slot_".$i."'>".$fetch->{"slot_".$i}."</td>";
               $lineCount++;
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Screenshot of html:

[image: Screenshot of html]

(The numbers are value in the database.)

I have tried to get this to work for days now without luck. 
I got close using this (link: [redips example page](http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/example01/)). 
Using the option: Switch content.

**The Problem:** I currently suck at JavaScript :)
I can’t get the functionality to work.
The biggest problem i'm facing is the drag and drop, and switch part of javaScript.
I also have trouble see how to instant update the DB using ajax.

I’m not even sure if this is possible to accomplice but, I would love to have your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have to know more about the problems you are facing: When does the the problem happen?
Have you tried to make a var_dump of your query? etc.:

```
$query  = $conn->query($sql) or die var_dump($conn->error);
```

Just to get an idea of what is happening.. :)

Besides that I can se that you havent used to loops to create the table. You have to make a for-loop that creates a row and within that a for-loop that creates the cells for that row. That make sense?

Comment: The Problem:
I currently suck at JavaScript :)
I can’t get the functionality to work.
The biggest problem i'm facing is the drag and drop, and switch part of javaScript.
I also have trouble see how to instant update the DB using ajax.

Comment: The PHP code is just something fast I made to visualize my idear, but you are right there is a far better way to do that.

Comment: I dont think you'll avoid to get into javascript a little big. One thing you should look at is jquery's implementation of draggable: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/. When it comes to updating the DB with ajax, just think of each ajax call as an entirely new run for your php script. Then you add the parameters to the ajax call and insert them into the DB using mysql. I hope that gives you a hint. :)

Comment: You are right. I need to learn javascript, but I have solved the problem. And I will be posting the answer later.